# Semaphore solution to reader-writer: order between updating reader count and waiting or signaling on read/write binary semaphore?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, computer-science, semaphore

From Operating System Concepts

> In the solution to the ﬁrst readers–writers problem, the reader
>   processes share the following data structures:
>
> ```
> semaphore rw mutex = 1;
> semaphore mutex = 1;
> int read_count = 0;
>
> do {
> wait(rw_mutex);
> . . .
> /* writing is performed */
> . . .
> signal(rw_mutex);
> } while (true);
> ```
>
> Figure 5.11 The structure of a writer process.
>
> ```
> do {
> wait(mutex);
> read count++;
> if (read_count == 1)
>     wait(rw mutex);
> signal(mutex);
> . . .
> /* reading is performed */
> . . .
> wait(mutex);
> read count--;
> if (read_count == 0)
>     signal(rw_mutex);
> signal(mutex);
> } while (true);
> ```
>
> Figure 5.12 The structure of a reader process.
>
> The semaphores `mutex` and `rw_mutex` are initialized to 1; read count
>   is initialized to 0. The semaphore  `rw_mutex` is common to both
>   reader and writer processes. The `mutex` semaphore is used to ensure
>   mutual exclusion when the variable read count is updated. The read
>   count variable keeps track of how many processes are currently reading
>   the object. The semaphore `rw_mutex` functions as a mutual exclusion
>   semaphore for the writers. It is also used by the ﬁrst or last reader
>   that enters or exits the critical section. It is not used by  readers
>   who enter or exit while other readers are in their critical sections.

1. Why is `wait`/`signal` on `rw_mutex` guarded by semaphore `mutex`?
2. In the structure of a reader process, Can I switch the order between
   updaing `read_count` and `wait`/`signal` on `rw_mutex`, as
   following?

   ```
   do {
   wait(mutex);
   if (read_count == 0)
       wait(rw_mutex);
   read count++;
   signal(mutex);
   . . .
   /* reading is performed */
   . . .
   wait(mutex);
   if (read_count == 1)
       signal(rw_mutex);
   read count--;
   signal(mutex);
   } while (true);
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you have no any further comments, or ask for elaboration otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why is `wait`/`signal` on `rw_mutex` guarded by semaphore `mutex`?

Imagine it's not, i.e. only `read_count` lines are guarded, and that you have reader threads α and β.

α increases `read_count`, executes `signal(mutex)`, and goes to executing `if (read_count == 1)`, and — bah! — CPU scheduler decides *"enough, let other threads to have a fun too!"*, and starts executing thread β.

Thread β locks `mutex`, increases `read_count`, releases `mutex`, and also starts executing `if (read_count == 1)`. Now, because read_count is 2, comparisons in both threads fails, so none of readers take the `rw_mutex`, and your writer goes writing over the data being read.

> 2. In the structure of a reader process, Can I switch the order between updating `read_count` and  `wait`/`signal` on `rw_mutex`, as following?

Yes, you can. The distinction is purely semantical: the original reads as *"We're about to read, so increase `read_count`, and if we're the only reader, lock `rw_mutex`. Perform reading. Then, as we're done, decrease `read_count`, and if we were the last reader, unlock `rw_mutex`"*.

Your variant reads as *"if nobody reads, lock `rw_mutex`. Then increase `read_count`. Perform reading. Then, if we were the only reader, unlock `rw_mutex`. Decrease `read_count`"*.

---

It might out of slight interest though, that if the author have used your variant, my answer to the first question would've been a bit longer because additionally, in the part of code with `signal(rw_mutex)`, you could've get a deadlock :Ь

Also, the concept author is describing in C++ is the [std::shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex).